# Cakephp: pass parameter or data to another page

Tags: cakephp, parameters

Our group create a database for patron to attend an event (booking) which has lots of entities.

We have three tables: patron, booking, booking_patron (join table).

We want to create 2 pages in the view (add.ctp and add2.ctp) of booking_patron.

Page add.ctp has a drop down box which lists booking ID and a submit button.
Page add2.ctp should appear the booking ID that we chose before (in add.ctp). Also in add2.ctp, we did make a function that user can create a patron and assign that patron to the booking ID.

BookingsPatronsController.php

```
public function add() {
    $bookings = $this->BookingsPatron->Booking->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('bookings', 'patrons'));
}
public function add2($booking_id = null) {

    $patrons = $this->BookingsPatron->Patron->find('list');
    $bookings = $this->BookingsPatron->Booking->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('bookings', 'patrons'));
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->BookingsPatron->Patron->create();

        if ($this->BookingsPatron->Patron->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Sign In Successful");

            $this->BookingsPatron->create();

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Well.... done'));

            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add3'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('We can not add your information. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: we don't know how to get the booking ID from add.ctp to add2.ctp.
At the moment, we use a drop down box that list booking ID in add2.ctp to choose the booking; we want to change that to a static text field that appears the booking ID from add.ctp.

We also have a function that can create a new patron in add2.ctp. We want to assign the new patron to the chosen booking ID from add.ctp

add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Booking.booking_id');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Create'), array('action' => 'add3')); ?>
```

add2.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('BookingsPatron'); ?>
<fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Booking.booking_id');?>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td class="heading">Name: </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Patron.patrons_name', array('label' => '', 'div' => 'formLabel'));?></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td class="heading">E-mail: </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Patron.patrons_email', array('label' => '', 'div' => 'formLabel'));?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="heading">Age: </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Patron.patrons_age', array('label' => '', 'div' => 'formLabel'));?></td>
    <td></td><td></td>        
    <td class="heading">Company: </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Patron.patrons_company', array('label' => '', 'div' => 'formLabel'));?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="heading">Postcode: </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Patron.patrons_postcode', array('label' => '', 'div' => 'formLabel'));?></td>
    <td></td><td></td>        
    <td class="heading">Gender: </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Patron.patrons_gender', array('label' => '', 'div' => 'formLabel', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => array('Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female')));?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">PH: 1300 7 34726</td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td><?php  echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('class' => 'classSubmitButton', 'title' => 'Sbumit')); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: You could temporary save it in the session; `$this->Session->write('booking_id', $id);`

Comment: ty for the solution, but i just dont get it (im new). where should i add this code? is it add.ctp or add function in controller

Comment: In that case you should read the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#sessions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
         $this->Session->write('booking_id', $this->request->data['Booking']['booking_id']);
         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add2')); // Line added
    }
    $bookings = $this->BookingsPatron->Booking->find('list'); 
    $this->set(compact('bookings', 'patrons'));
}
```

And to retreive the ID use this in your add2() function

```
$booking_id = $this->Session->read('booking_id');
```

Update

edit add.ctp -- This needs to be a form, not just a link, otherwise you don't submit the booking ID

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('Booking');
    echo $this->Form->input('Booking.booking_id');
    echo $this->Form->end(__('Create'));
?>
```

Comment: Ty for your help, but can you show me how to link from add.ctp page to add2.ctp page. At the moment, I used <fieldset>
 
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Booking.booking_id');?>
    
     </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?> When I submit, how can I link to the add2.ctp. thanks. I tried to use $this->redirect(array('action'=>'add2')); inside the if loop of add function

Comment: I updated my answer, does this work for you? (see the line added)

Comment: I tried it and that didn't work for me. When I clicked on Submit button, it still stays the same page; didnt navigate to add2.ctp at all

Comment: OK, my mistake, you also need to make a change in add.ctp, check my update above.

Comment: Ty for taking your time. But it still doesn't work. It doesnot create the record (id, booking_id, patron_id) for the bookings_patrons table (even though it created a new patron into patron table. The only problem right now is to let the Bookings_Patrons controller (add2 function) to read the booking ID to pass to create a new record. Thanks for taking your time. NOTE: did call the {$booking_id = $this->Session->read('booking_id');} or {$booking_id = $this->Session->read('booking_id');$this->BookingsPatron->Booking->create();$this->BookingsPatron->Booking->id = $booking_id;}

Comment: I am sorry, but I'd advise you to take a close look on the documentation. Especially the blog example and the part on saving model data. I think the basics of your app are not completely fine. Just a couple of hints, make sure that the first time u create the database entry by using $this->Model->create(); and on updating the record (in add2 and add3) make sure you use just before you save the data $this->Model->id = $id;. I also think you need to use the $this->Model->getLastInsertId(); to get the last inserted id, this you might need to store in a session. And check your model associations.